# checkbox filtering system

Tags: javascript, jquery

I came across this page at [walmart.com](http://www.walmart.com/browse/Computers/Desktop-Computers/_/N-96fg?browsein=true&catNavId=3951&ic=48_0&ref=%20428236) and on the left side of the page is a checkbox filtering system that is done on the client side. When you check the price checkbox selection it filters out the brands and disables enables/disables them etc.

When i had a look at the source code the checkboxes have no values and when i tried to find the `REFINEMENT.clicked` event I couldn't find it when I downloaded the page. It's a very big page with lots of code and would prob take a long time to go through it.

I was wondering how could I implement this filtering system in jquery for the client side. You could use a array that stores values but how would i know which properties the filters have as each page would show different filters (other than price range) based upon the product type.

If someone could point me in the right direction or give an example as to what to do that would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a simple ajax call.

Here is a very similar question [Filter divs/table rows based on checkbox criteria -Javascript/JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504407/filter-divs-table-rows-based-on-checkbox-criteria-javascript-jquery)

Here is the [url when the top checkbox](http://www.walmart.com/browse/dynamicupdate?upt=count&dept=428236&dval=4292450273%7C1500001%7C1500689%7C1500275%7C1500031%7C1500332&exp=500986%7C500500%7C500000%7C501059%7C500858%7C500564%7C500501%7C500708%7C1000123&keywords=&si=&tab=All&nosess=true) is checked and it results in a JSON reply.

```
{"dvals":[{"id":"500580", "count":"16"},...
```

So they contact the server each time

```
clicked:function(K){var J=F(K);if(!J.disabled||J.checked){J.checked=!J.checked;ASN.RefinementBox.check(J);}},

check:function(K){try{if(!K.checked){ASN.RefinementBox.uncheck(K.id);ASN.BubbleMsg.bubbleMsg(K.id);}else{if(!REFINEMENT.maximumCheck(K)){A.putDval(K.id);ASN.RefinementBox.sendSelection();ASN.BubbleMsg.bubbleMsg(K.id);}}}catch(J){}},uncheck:function(J){A.removeDval(J);ASN.RefinementBox.sendSelection();}
```

In the page itself it has stuff like

```
WALMART.quicklook.items.push({"itemId":16472509,"price":'<!--Start qlPrevNextPricing Tag--><span class="prevNextDefaultText"><span class="PriceL"></span><span class="bigPriceText2">$398.</span><span class="smallPriceText2">00</span><span></span></span><!--End qlPrevNextPricing Tag-->',"thumbnailURL":"http://i.walmartimages.com/i/p/00/88/61/11/62/0088611162102_60X60.gif"});
```

and similar to hold prices to calculate and to show

Comment: i checked out those links and there samples didn't work. where did you get the {"dvals":[{"id":"500580", "count":"16"},...  code from and where did you find the click and check events for refinement. I really want to implement this. My other questions is for id and count in the json array how do i make up my tables in asp.net to contain these values and generate this type of data. I've never done ajax so this will be new to me

Comment: I got the Filter divs/table working my question is what do i generate the id's from in the json array before i attempt this

Comment: I was wondering how do you disable the checkboxes based on selection using {"dvals":[{"id":"500580", "count":"16"},... on walmart.com it also performs subtraction when you check the checkboxes for the count property

Comment: What I mean is when you check the price selection it performs some calculation on the brands checkboxes and enbales/disables.

Comment: Sure, it is all sent to the server. It can do the calculation or you can loop over the JSON reply.

Comment: From what i see in the {"dvals":[{"id":"500580", "count":"16"},... is that it's just an id and count what i don't understand is how the price checking selection works cos in the json string it doesn't return a price field can you explain to me in simple terms whats going cos i want to make this in asp.net and jquery.

Comment: What kinda of processing would be done on the server. and where did you find the clicked and check event from

Comment: Have a JS object for the items with description, price and number of units selected. It is not rocket science. Do the calculation on both server and client to be sure you do not get fooled by someone hacking the JS

Comment: I've never done ajax requests before. I presume you create a url param like param=1,2,3,4 numbers 1-4 correspond to the checkboxes. I can't quite understand the dval on the query string im new at this. I thought that the dval=somenumber would be a comma seperated list but it's not, if could just guide me that would help get me started. Im definitly no rocket scientist at this

Comment: Im gonna use asp.net I don't know any PHP. So could you exaplain or give me an example as to what you mean by jquery serializing my form and sending it to the server. Im sory for not understanding all this but once i get it i'll know what to do exactly.Is that what they did serialize the form. can you give me a code example so i can get the idea and get started.

Comment: thanks i'll study it and get back to you. Have you tried using this technique or done filtering like walmarts website.

Comment: Not in ASP, but it is a well known technique and I have written scripts to filter before Ajax was big

Answer (score -1):

The [PicNet Table Filter Plugin](http://www.picnet.com.au/picnet_table_filter.html) for jQuery lets you filter a table of data with check boxes or search fields. Just make sure your table contains the data to be filtered, even if they are in hidden columns that the user can't see.

Comment: that is not what i was looking for that's totally different. That only filters a table im working with a database so all records will not be exposed i.e paging etc. there is obviously some kind of data that they are filtering against